# Prove a recurrent relation for $\int\frac{\sin^nx}{\cos^mx}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How do we prove $$\int\dfrac{\sin^nx}{\cos^mx}dx=\dfrac{\sin^{n-1}x}{(m-1)\cos^{m-1}x}-\dfrac{n-1}{m-1}\int\dfrac{\sin^{n-2}x}{\cos^{m-2}x}dx,m\ne-1?$$

At first I decided to take $m=n$.
In this case we can write the given integral as $$-\int\dfrac{\sin^{n+2}x}{\cos^nx}d\cot x=-\dfrac{1}{1-n}\int\sin^2xd(\cot^{-n+1}x)=\\\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sin^2x\cot^{-n+1}x-\dfrac{1}{n-1}\int\cot^{-n+1}xd\sin^2x=\\\dfrac{1}{n-1}\dfrac{\sin^2x\cos^{-n+1}x}{\sin^{-n+1}x}-\dfrac{1}{n-1}\int\dfrac{2\sin x\cos x\cos^{-n+1}x}{\sin^{-n+1}x}dx$$

I really don't know how to proceed when $m$ and $n$ are not equal, though. We don't even know if $n>m$ (or the other way around) which seems to be important in my try which is for $n=m$. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to solve the problem by *integration by parts.*

Comment: Why do they need to be equal? Just use integration by parts and pair one sine with the cosine to integrate.

Comment: @podiki, can you be a little more specific? How do I pair them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show what it asks of you, just use integration by parts, let's note the following:
$$\int \frac{\sin^{n}x}{\cos^{m}x }dx = \int \frac{\sin^{n-1}x \sin x}{\cos^{m}x }dx $$
Now let's use integration by parts considering the variables $u$ and $v$ as:
$u =\sin^{n-1}x$ y $dv = \frac{ \sin x}{\cos^{m}x }dx$ so let's notice that $du = (n-1)\sin^{n-2}x$ $dx$ y $v =\frac{ 1}{(m-1)\cos^{m-1}x } $ Therefore, substituting in integration by parts we have to:
$$\int \frac{\sin^{n}x}{\cos^{m}x }dx = \int \frac{\sin^{n-1}x \sin x}{\cos^{m}x }dx = uv- \int vdu =$$
$$ \sin^{n-1}x\frac{1}{(m-1)\cos^{m-1}x}- \int \frac{ 1}{(m-1)\cos^{m-1}x } (n-1)\sin^{n-2}x dx$$.
which is what is requested in the problem.